# How to understand OwlApp { finish() } , while the defination of function OwlApp is fun OwlApp(finishActivity: () -> Unit) {}?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am studying about JetPack Compose and learning the official example: OwlApp(https://material.io/design/material-studies/owl.html). I can't understand the followed code:

In MainActivity file:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // This app draws behind the system bars, so we want to handle fitting system windows
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

        setContent {
            // ?? finishActivity类型的参数呢，OwlApp(finishActivity_){finish()}
           ** OwlApp { finish() }**
        }
    }
}
```

In OwlApp file:

```
@Composable
**fun OwlApp(finishActivity: () -> Unit) {**
    ProvideWindowInsets {
        BlueTheme {
            val tabs = remember { CourseTabs.values() }
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            Scaffold(
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface,
                bottomBar = { OwlBottomBar(navController = navController, tabs) }
            ) { innerPaddingModifier ->
                NavGraph(
                    finishActivity = finishActivity,
                    navController = navController,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPaddingModifier)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could not understand the use of `OwlApp { finish() }` because the args should be there.

Hope for help, TAHNKS